# refetchQueries in Mutation Component of React Apollo Client is not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have a `<Query />` in my `Home.js` file

## Home.js

```
<Query
      query={GET_TODOS_BY_PRODUCT}
      variables={{ id: state.get("selectedProduct.id"), completed: true }}
    >
      {({ data: { product } }) => {
        return <Main todos={product.todos} hashtag={product.hashtag} />;
      }}
</Query>
```

In my `Main.js` file I have `<Mutation />` component -

## Main.js

```
<Mutation
    key={v4()}
    mutation={SWITCH_SELECTED_PRODUCT}
    refetchQueries={() => {
        console.log("refetchQueries", product.id);
        return {
            query: GET_TODOS_BY_PRODUCT,
            variables: { id: product.id }
        };
    }}
>
{switchSelectedProduct => (
        <Product
            onClick={() => {
                switchSelectedProduct({
                    variables: { id: product.id, name: product.name }
                });
            }}
            highlight={
                data.selectedProduct
                    ? product.name === data.selectedProduct.name
                    : i === 0
            }
        >
            <Name>{product.name}</Name>
        </Product>
    )}
</Mutation>
```

When `switchSelectedProduct` is called inside `<Mutation />` component, it runs `refetchQueries` as I see the `console.log("refetchQueries", product.id);` statement but I don't see the updated results in the `<Query />` component in `Home.js` file.

How do I tell `<Query />` component in `Home.js` to get notified when `refetchQueries` is run in `Main.js` file?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with some help. There is apparently a bug in `refetchQueries` as it does not update data from another component. But `refetchQueries` was not needed at all.

I wrapped my `Home` component with another `Query` like:

## Home.js

```
<Query
    query={GET_ALL_PRODUCTS}
    variables={{ id: state.get("user.id") }}
>
    {({ data: { user } }) => {
        const { id, name } = user.products ? user.products[0] : [];
        return <Main id={id} name={name} />;
    }}
</Query>
```

Then I also wrapped my `Main` component with another `Query` so it changes state when mutation is applied. This way you don't need `refetchQueries` at all. Just wrap your `Mutation` or `Query` component when `Mutation` from another or same component is performed.

## Main.js

```
<Query query={GET_SELECTED_PRODUCT}>
    <Mutation
            key={v4()}
            mutation={SWITCH_SELECTED_PRODUCT}
    >
    {switchSelectedProduct => (
                    <Product
                            onClick={() => {
                                    switchSelectedProduct({
                                            variables: { id: product.id, name: product.name }
                                    });
                            }}
                            highlight={
                                    data.selectedProduct
                                            ? product.name === data.selectedProduct.name
                                            : i === 0
                            }
                    >
                            <Name>{product.name}</Name>
                    </Product>
            )}
    </Mutation>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 14):

From docs: `refetchQueries: (mutationResult: FetchResult) => Array<{ query: DocumentNode, variables?: TVariables} | string>`, so probably you need to return an array instead of just the object

```
<Mutation
  key={v4()}
  mutation={SWITCH_SELECTED_PRODUCT}
  refetchQueries={() => {
     console.log("refetchQueries", product.id)
     return [{
        query: GET_TODOS_BY_PRODUCT,
        variables: { id: product.id }
    }];
}}
>
```

Comment: Hey @alexhenkel so this worked I tried it again with some other parameters but I still can't see my `<Query />` component being re-rendered. That's my other question.

Comment: Works great. Thanks. Also see its documentation: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning a function you have to directly pass the array of object

```
<Mutation refetchQueries={[{query:YOUR_QUERY}>
 ...code
</Mutation>
```

Answer (score 0):

I d fight a lot to refetchQueries which are in another React Component, and best solution, not the easiest or smartest I guess, is  to pass the refetch() function from a component to the other

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/